# Globally change action column header for all model views in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How can I globally change action column header for all model views in yii2?

```
[
 'header' => 'Actions',
 'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
 'template' => '{view} {update}'
]
```

I need to change the `'header' => 'Actions'` for views of all my models.

Is it possible to change it globally instead of making the change in each and every model view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`DependencyInjection`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-di-container.html):

```
\Yii::$container->set('yii\grid\ActionColumn', ['header' => 'Header here']);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I'm sorry, I'm a newbie.  Where to place this code?

Comment: You can put it in `config/bootstrap.php`.

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my time  :)